# Apache rewrites - languages

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm having some problems with rewrites... can please someone help me out here?

Currently I have this:

```
Redirect example.com/*/ to example.com/en/* if da,de, and en were not found.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/(da|de|en|en-uk)/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en/$1 [L,R]
```

This wasn't the problem - the problem is with the following:
1. example.com/xx/* ->  example.com/en/* - for any two letters which are not in (da,de,en|en-uk)

How to craft this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(da|de|en|en-uk)/
  RewriteRule ^/../(.*)$ /en/$1 [L,R]
```

There are a few problems that I can see with your original code:

There is a period and a dollar sign in the RewriteCond, at the end. That would only match /xx/X. Remove the dollar sign to match any length on the end. Remove the "." before dollar sign to allow for empty matches after the slash.